# Disparity Map post processing in OpenFrameworks

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, openframeworks, stereoscopy

After long hours I finally managed to get a stereo disparity map with a single camera. The result is rather spotty as one would expect, so I would like to apply some filter to improve the quality. The problem is that I'm not using pure OpenCV, but the plugin for OpenFrameworks (ofxCv), meaning I can't use this:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html

There has to be a way how I can apply the WLS filter, or something similar in this situation. WLS appears to be implemented in OpenCV, but I can't access it through the plugin, and direct access also doesn't seem to work.

Does anybody know how I can apply that filter, or has any other, general, disparity map post-processing advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what OpenCV functionality is available to you. But just a suggestion, maybe use the implementation from OpenCV in your project. Look at the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/master/modules/ximgproc/src/disparity_filters.cpp

Copy any additional files you may need to your project and try building. With basic OpenCV support you might be able to make it work.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but the file has just enough dependencies on other imgproc classes  to make it quite impractical to implement like that.

Comment: I had to port 4 files (DisparityWLSFilter/FGSFilter h+cpp) and write one to emulate their dependencies, but in the end it worked out fine and was less work then I made it out to be. Thanks.